# Nested commands in EJS not executing

Tags: javascript, ejs

Can someone let me know why the `console.log()` statement nested inside the for loop not work at all. In fact, anything I put after the `{` and before the `%>` does not seem to affect the code at all.

Here is the code:

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) { %>   
    <% console.log("hello") %>
    <script>checkdate();</script>
    <tr id = "data">
        <td><%= i + 1 %></td>
        <td><%= users[i].name %></td>
        <td><%= users[i].email %></td>
        <td><%= users[i].material %></td>
        <td><%= users[i].frequency %></td>
    
        <!-- <td><%= users[i].date %></td> -->
        <td id="date">
            <script>
                date = "<%= users[i].date %>"
                var d_names = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
    
                var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March",
                    "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                    "October", "November", "December");
    
                var d = new Date(date);
                var curr_day = d.getDay();
                var curr_date = d.getDate();
                var sup = "";
                if (curr_date == 1 || curr_date == 21 || curr_date == 31) {
                    sup = "st";
                } else if (curr_date == 2 || curr_date == 22) {
                    sup = "nd";
                } else if (curr_date == 3 || curr_date == 23) {
                    sup = "rd";
                } else {
                    sup = "th";
                }
                var curr_month = d.getMonth();
                var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    
                document.write(d_names[curr_day] + " " + curr_date + "<SUP>" + sup + "</SUP> " + m_names[curr_month] + " " +
                    curr_year);
            </script>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/update-user?id=<%= users[i]._id%>" class="btn border-shadow update">
                <span class="text-gradient"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></span>
            </a>
            <a class="btn border-shadow delete" data-id=<%= users[i]._id%>>
                <span class="text-gradient"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
```

**UPDATE**
I updated the code to include an if statement inside the for loop instead of the console.log statement and now ti gives me the error

> Could not find matching close tag for "<%".

Here's the code:

```
<% for(var i = 0, todays_date = new Date(), given_date = new Date("<%= users[i].date %>") ; i < users.length; i++) { %>   
   <% todays_date.setHours(0,0,0,0); given_date.setHours(0,0,0,0); if(todays_date == given_date){ %>
    <script>
        console.log("cheeky");
    </script>  
    <tr id = "data">
        <td><%= i + 1 %></td>
        <td><%= users[i].name %></td>
        <td><%= users[i].email %></td>
        <td><%= users[i].material %></td>
        <td><%= users[i].frequency %></td>
    
        <!-- <td><%= users[i].date %></td> -->
        <td id="date">
            <script>
                date = "<%= users[i].date %>"
                var d_names = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
    
                var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March",
                    "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                    "October", "November", "December");
    
                var d = new Date(date);
                var curr_day = d.getDay();
                var curr_date = d.getDate();
                var sup = "";
                if (curr_date == 1 || curr_date == 21 || curr_date == 31) {
                    sup = "st";
                } else if (curr_date == 2 || curr_date == 22) {
                    sup = "nd";
                } else if (curr_date == 3 || curr_date == 23) {
                    sup = "rd";
                } else {
                    sup = "th";
                }
                var curr_month = d.getMonth();
                var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    
                document.write(d_names[curr_day] + " " + curr_date + "<SUP>" + sup + "</SUP> " + m_names[curr_month] + " " +
                    curr_year);
            </script>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/update-user?id=<%= users[i]._id%>" class="btn border-shadow update">
                <span class="text-gradient"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></span>
            </a>
            <a class="btn border-shadow delete" data-id=<%= users[i]._id%>>
                <span class="text-gradient"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
    <% } %>
```

Comment: Because it is output as simple text. It is written in your HTML, like regular text. You need to put it inside `<script>` tags, so it is interpreted as script and executed at runtime.

Comment: Hmm, ok makes sense. I updated the code to include an if statement, but that gives the error Could not find matching close tag for "<%". Updated code can be seen above